# what does it mean to declare a NSNumber variable as property copy

Tags: objective-c, copy, properties, retain

I am still learning ..., so for the following property

```
@property (copy) NSNumber *foo;
```

What the copy really do? make a copy of the (value of) foo and put it to new place? Just like a copy constructor?

And also to clarify, the following is basically doing a AddRef, right?

```
@property (retain) NSNumber *foo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What the copy really do?

In general, `NSNumber` is immutable -- I'd expect that `copy` in those cases would be implemented using `retain`:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone {
  return [self retain];
}
```

> And also to clarify, the following is basically doing a AddRef, right?

Well, synthesizing it will add the reference counting boilerplate - the actual operation is more complex and takes the generalized form:

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSNumber *)arg {
  NSNumber * prev = foo;
  foo = [arg retain]; // << or foo = [arg copy]; if you have specified 'copy'
  [prev release];
}
```

Comment: Of course if you use non atomic vs atomic the boilerplate changes. nonatomic is closer to the above code. Since you did not specify non atomic, there will be @synchronize calls happening under the hood too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties

Comment: non-atomic ==> code will only be called from a single thread. without the nonatomic keyword, the code is _more_ thread safe, or better thought as you are _able_ to write thread safe code with atomic getters and setters.

Comment: @Tom Anderson Yes, I know the example resembles nonatomic implementation (but yours is a fine note for others). The reason for this? This is a beginner Cocoa question, and I said the example is a *generalized* form of what is happening (within the context of the question).

Comment: Some notes about your other comments:

1) nonatomic properties can be thread safe, and they can operate in multithreaded contexts. After all, we were able to create threadsafe concurrent Cocoa programs prior to ObjC-V2.
2) Atomic properties are *not* implemented with `@synchronized`. This is a popular misconception -- it also means that programs which a) use `@synchronized` and b) expect atomic property implementations will also use them have many concurrent design errors waiting to be found.
(cont)

Comment: (cont) 3) Atomic properties are not at all a substitute for proper thread safety. They only protect data in a very limited scope.

Atomic properties alone are still unquestionably unsafe in concurrent execution -- they only reduce the probability that a threading error will occur (or be exposed) during execution. That's not even desirable - IMO, I'd rather the defect were exposed earlier on and occur more frequently because errors in concurrent programs can be horribly difficult to reproduce. (cont)

Comment: (cont) The short of it is: atomic properties + `@synchronized` are really not good solutions for nontrivial concurrent programs. Under those circumstances, neither atomic properties nor `@synchronized` are ideal.

Answer (score 1):

See the description of properties here:
http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103

`copy` means that assigning a value into the property will make a copy of the input value.

`retain` means that you won't get an actual copy; you'll get the same object with an extra retain on it. So if it's modified elsewhere, you'll see the modifications in both places.

For `NSNumber`s, they are immutable, so copy and retain are functionally equivalent.